# Problems check username input against flat file for user creation

Tags: perl

I am working on a user login and am having trouble with the user creation part. My problem is that I am trying to check the input username against a text file to see if that username already exists. I can't seem to get it to compare the input username to the array that I have brought in. I have tried two different ways of accomplishing this. One using an array and another using something I read online that I don't quite understand. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my attempt using an array to compare off of
http://codepad.org/G7xmsf3z

Here is my second attempt
http://codepad.org/SbeqmdbG

Comment: When I see questions like this, I always think "How similar should user names be allowed to be?" I.e. Should the username `EXample` be allowed, if `Example` is registered? Or should `emily` and `emily.` both be allowed? In short, decide the rules first, then make a subroutine for it, that follows those rules.

Comment: You will have a race condition here that will mess up your registration system. You must figure out how to lock out other processes from updating your list of accounts until your current program finished execution and releases its lock. Locking files is workable but not as easy as storing the info in a proper DB that will handle locking for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt, try to put the if inside of the loop:

```
foreach my $pair(@incomingarray) {
    (my $name,my $value) = split (/:/, $pair);

    if ($name eq $username) {
      print p("Username is already taken, try again");
      close(YYY);
      print end_html();
    }
    else {
      open(YYY, ">>password.txt");
      print YYY $username.":".$hashpass."\n";
      print p("Your account has been created sucessfully");
     close(YYY);
     print end_html();
   }
}
```

In you second attempt, I think you should try and change the line:

```
if (%users eq $username) {
```

with this one:

```
if (defined $users{$username}) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated above regarding locking the flatfile from other processes there is the issue with scaling too. the more users you have the slower the lookup will be.

I started years ago with a flat file, believing I would never scale enough to require a real database and didn't want to learn how to use mySQL for example. Eventually after flatfile corruptions and long lookup times I had no choice but to move to a database.

Later you will find yourself wanting to store user preferences and such, it's easy to add a new field to a database. Flatfile will end up having the overhead of splitting each line into separate fields.

I'd suggest you do it properly with a database.

Comment: this is all being done for the sake of learning, it is going to be hooked up to a database as well. That is what I will be trying to accomplish next week with this, but for now I am just trying to get the flat file working.

Comment: Even a [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database would be better than a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment, you should not be using a flatfile to hold your user info. You should use a proper database that will handle concurrent access for you rather than having to understand and code up how to deal with all of that yourself!

If you insist on using an array, you can search it with grep() if it is not "too large":

```
if (grep /^$username:/, @incomingarray) {
    print "user name '$username' is already registered, try again\n";
}
else {
    print "user name '$username' is not already registered\n";
}
```

I see some other problems in your code as well.

You should always prefer lexical (my) variables over package (our) variables.
Why do you think (erroneously) that $name and $username cannot be lexical variables?

You should always use the 3-arg form of open() and check its return value like in your 2nd code example. Your open() in the 1st code example is how it was done many many years ago.